# Add selected Cell text label to array when button is clicked

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an app right now that has a table view with multiple cells that were loaded from an array.  I delimited the text in a text view to separate the text into components that then were added to an array.  From there I set the text label of each cell to each component in the array.  So I have something that looks like this...

[image]

And I want to be able to select a cell and it highlights the cell, then I want to be able to click one of the buttons on the right.  When I click a button it takes the text label of that cell and stores it in an array as a component.

I don't know how I would go about writing the code for "take the text label of the selected cell and store it as a component."  Is there a way to detect if the cell is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a `NSMutableArray` to achieve this because you can add and remove objects from it on the fly:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)myButtonClicked
{
    NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
    if ([myMutableArray containsObject:cell.textLabel.text]) {
        [myMutableArray removeObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    }else{
        [myMutableArray addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, thats exactly what I needed!!!  Is there a way then if I click to add something thats already been added, to take it out.  So if I didn't want to add that certain cell, I just hit the button again and it takes out that component?

Comment: @Craig Any time! Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

An even better approach is to take the text from your array that provides data to the table view and put that in the other array. I'll call them `sourceArray` and `destinationArray`.

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *string = [self.sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.destinationArray addObject:string];
}
```

I suspect though that the `indexPathForSelectedRow` method was the one you were looking for. If you still need to go with the label text, modify the handler as shown:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *string = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    [self.destinationArray addObject:string];
}
```

Hope this helps!